# What exactly azimuthal symmetry means?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves, scattering, scattering-cross-section, spherical-harmonics

In quantum mechanics, when discussing scattering by a potential, it is written that we are assuming the potential is spherically symmetric so the function cannot depend on $φ$.

Azimuthal symmetry remains the same.
I had read about the azimuthal angle in spherical coordinate system, but I don't get the concept of azimuthal symmetry. What exactly is azimuthal symmetry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a quantity has azimuthal symmetry, then it is independent of the azimuthal angle (usually denoted by $\phi$). A spherically symmetric quantity also possesses azimuthal symmetry, since it only depends on the radius (usually denoted by r in spherical coordinates and $\rho$ in cylindrical ones.).